# Hibernate. OneToOne mapping problems

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable{

/**
 * This is my Customer entity object
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 9037154862690840147L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="Cust_Id")
private int customerId;

@Column(name="First_Name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="Last_Name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="Gender")
private String gender;

@Column(name="Email")
private String email;

@Column(name="Password")
private String password;

@Column(name="City")
private String city;

@Column(name="State")
private String state;

@Column(name="Country")
private String country;

@Column(name="Phone_No")
private String phoneNumber;

@Column (name="Zip_Code")
private int zipCode;

@Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_NM")
private String lastUpdatedName;

@Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_DTM")
private Date lastUpdatedTime;


@OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private RoleOfUser roleOfUser;





This is my Role of user entity object
@Entity
@Table(name = "role_of_user")
public class RoleOfUser implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "Role_Id")
private Integer roleId;

@Column(name = "Role_Name")
private String roleName;

@Column(name = "First_Name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="Last_Name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "Created_NM")
private String createdName;

@Column(name = "Created_DTM")
private Date createdDate;

@Column(name = "Last_Update_NM")
private String lastUpdatedName;

@Column(name = "Last_Update_DTM")
private Date lastUpdatedDate;

@Column (name = "Status")
private String status;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Customer customer;



@Column(name = "Customer_Cust_Id")
@GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
@GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign",  parameters =       @Parameter(name = "property", value = "customer"))
private Integer customerId;
```

customerId from customer entity table need to be a foreign key to Customer_cust_id in RoleOfUser table. 
i ran the above code and it says Customer_cust_id cannot be null.
How do i map foreign keys?
Role_id is already a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Using primitives in my persistence classes has always been a pet peeve of mine because it can lead to some misleading errors, so I'd start with changing `int customerId` to `Integer customerId`.

Next, it sounds like `Customer` should be your parent table and `RoleOfUser` should be the child. The problem here is that you are saying your tables are one-to-one, but you don't then join on the `@Id` column of `RoleOfUser`.

Consider doing something like this instead:

```
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CUST_ID")
    private Integer customerId;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE_OF_USER")
public class RoleOfUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private Integer roleId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_CUST_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUST_ID")
    private Customer customer
}
```

Finally, though, if these tables are truly one-to-one, why not just make them one wider table with more columns? Or if a user is allowed to have multiple roles, then you'll want to change that `@OneToOne` to be an `@ManyToOne`.